# Iterating reference Object List

Tags: java, performance, optimization, well-formed

Can anyone suggest me which option to choose and why ?

```
List<MyObject> list =  new ArrayList<MyObject>();
// insert some objects for it

1). for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i ++ ) {
       System.out.println(list.get(i).getAttribute1());
       System.out.println(list.get(i).getAttribute2());
    }

2). for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i ++ ) {
        MyObject obj = list.get(i);
        System.out.println(obj.getAttribute1());
        System.out.println(obj.getAttribute2());
    }
```

Yes , I know ... they will produce same results but I would like to know which option was more efficient , well-format , widely use and why ? I just notice only that ***first option will write more longer than another*** between them. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The second option could be slightly better (one "get(i)" only), but usually compiler is smart enough to optimize both versions to be equal

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I assume first option will always look up in **list** object. Am I right ?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko How compiler **optimize both versions to be equal** ?

Comment: If optimization is switched off, the 1st option will be slightly worse: it calls list.get(i) twice, so the system should check bounds, compute shift ect. twice. When optimization is on, the compiler'll probably eliminate bounds check and precompute list.get(i) (as in the 1st option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option: 1** Get is used twice on the list which is an additional process

**Option: 2** Only one get is used which reduces the process. So this is better on compared to option:1

In both your options, the list.size() will be computed for each iteration of the for loop. To avoid this you can compute the length prior to iteration starts as,

```
for (int i = 0, length = list.size(); i < length; i ++) {
   // your code here

}
```

The efficient way is to use the for each loop as,

```
for (MyObject obj: list) {
  System.out.println(obj.getAttribute1);
}
```

Comment: yes , I know about **for each loop** . But I am not finding more efficient way . I just comparing these two options. In some case that we can't use **for each loop** , I got ambiguity which option to choose. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Cataclysm If my list is too large, then i will code with the option 2

Comment: ok ! If so , I will choose option 2 forever. I think my problem was fine. Thanks.

Comment: btw , my list also too large and I want to know which option is more reliable. So , I asked this question.